# How could I know that 3 sets of data have the same/different distribution?

Tags: distributions

I have 3 sets of data and I would like to know that what test I could use to find out that whether those sets of data have the same distribution.

Edit 1: If I use hypothesis tests to show there are no difference between means and variances of those data sets, does it mean that they have the same distribution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As eric Peterson said, i think the better is to compare the distributions two by two. You can so use the solutions hère :
[Comparison of 2 distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52305/comparison-of-2-distributions/52329#52329)

My opinion is that qqplot is just a first tool, as it is only visual. It is very practical to have a first guess but it is not sufficient at all. I recommend you to use a statistical test like kolmogorov-Smirnov test which tests exactly what you want : if two distributions are equal.

Using a test for mean and variance gives you useful information but it is not sufficient unless you know your distributions are gaussian ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realise that the n of those sets are large (> 250), could I assume that they are normal and than just using method that I mentioned?

Comment: Try a qqplot or a shappiro test to see if the hypothesis of normality works well

Comment: I have used minitab to test my data. K-S test, Anderson-Darling test and also Shappiro test show that those observed values are bigger than the p values. So it means that all of my data are not normally distributed, right?

I have also used a function in minitab called "Individual Distribution Identification" and it shows that my data are fit with normal distribution with Johnson Transformation (which is something that I don't get a clue of how it works).

What should I do now in order to answer my question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could run QQPlots for two distributions against each other to see if they're from the same distribtion.  If two datasets are, then the QQPlot will appear as a straight line.  Comparing each of the three distributions pairwise should let you know if any of the distributions differ.  You could also make density plots or histograms of each of the data sets and overlay them on top of each other.  QQPlot in R is in the stats package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

If I use hypothesis tests to show there are no difference between means and variances of those data sets, does it mean that they have the same distribution?