# Wilcoxon rank sum test methodology

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm comparing the performance of two algorihtms $A$ and $B$ based on a metric.

For each algorithm, I have $31$ independent samples that represent its performance. This samples are grouped in two sets: $X$ and $Y$ (algoritmh $A$ and algorithm $B$, respectively).

For this task, I'm using a Wilcoxon rank-sum test with a level of significance $\alpha=0.05$ on R

I have selected this nonparametric test because it makes no assumption
 about data distribution.

This is my methodology:

1. **Hypothesis**

   Let $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ be the means of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. 
   Then, the one-tailed test is defined as follows:

   -$H_0$: $E(X) = E(Y)$
    (the performance of both algorithms is similar)

   -$H_1$: $E(X) > E(Y)$
    (the performance of $A$ is better than $B$)
2. **Means**

   $E(X) = 36.87548$, $E(Y)=37.72585$

   `> summary(X)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.00   35.09   45.34   36.88   46.63   48.05`

   `> summary(Y)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    9.332  34.860  41.120  37.730  42.510  48.110`
3. **Compare $A$ vs $B$**

   `p = wilcox.test(X, Y, alternative="greater", conf.level=0.95)$p.value`

   If $p=0.0170 < \alpha = 0.05$, then $E(X)$ should be greater than $E(Y)$ (It's what I think, but it's not greater!), We can reject $H_0$, so we can conclude that: *algorithm $A$ outperforms algorithm $B$ with a significance level of $\alpha=0.05$*.
4. **Compare $B$ vs $A$**

   `p = wilcox.test(Y, X, alternative="greater", conf.level=0.95)$p.value`

   If $p=0.9835 > \alpha$, then $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ are similar (Again, It's my guess). We can not reject $H_0$, therefore we can conclude that: *$A$ and $B$ have similar performance*.

**Data**

```
X = c(  45.51885768, 35.65081119, 44.60124311, 15.39979541, 48.05143243, 47.90604081,
     7.58163868,  0.00000000, 40.94718019, 45.34194687, 28.55451125, 46.15113458,
    48.03542321, 47.91413840, 45.38912357, 47.10730083, 47.42726563, 47.80316539,
    34.51956662,  0.05853162, 45.29245167, 48.00199937, 45.28839538, 44.89017125,
    45.47222435,  7.32111177, 43.35755055, 45.52413737, 45.53528261, 45.45233121,
    3.04515436)

Y = c(  41.603296, 43.005620, 38.345339, 28.483733, 41.342548, 44.344933, 34.030309,
    42.012604, 35.718175, 45.203532, 40.482022, 45.345594, 41.155187, 41.141522,
    48.111677, 41.117034, 34.713158, 44.972073, 35.091889, 34.206018,  9.332199,
    39.776291, 28.236449, 13.792789, 35.016681, 41.699073, 41.203090, 47.988765,
    36.496740, 45.346652, 30.186485)
```

[image]

**Questions**

1. is The Wilcoxon rank sum test based on means (as I think in steps 3 and 4) or is based on medians?
2. Is it possible that $A$ can be better than $B$ and at the same time $E(X) < E(Y)$?
3. Is the following methodology correct?

   ```
   for x in (X, Y)

      for y in (X, Y)

      if x == y: continue

          p = wilcox.test(x, y, alternative="greater", conf.level=0.95)

      if p < alpha:
          x is better than y

      else 
          if p > alpha:
              p = wilcox.test(x, y, alternative="less", conf.level=0.95)

          if p < alpha:
              x is worse than y

      else
          x and y have similar performance
   ```
4. If I wish to test $A$ against several algorithms $B$, $C$, $...$, what could be the best approach to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have selected this nonparametric test because it makes no assumption about data distribution.

This is not quite the case; it makes some assumptions (such as continuity), it just doesn't assume a specific functional form.

> is The Wilcoxon rank sum test based on means (as I think in steps 3 and 4) or is based on medians?

Neither. It's the median of pairwise differences (two sample Hodges-Lehmann difference) - that we're dealing with.

See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67204/what-exactly-does-a-non-parametric-test-accomplish-what-do-you-do-with-the-res/67210#67210) for some discussion on that point (near the top of the post).

As whuber quite rightly points out below, under the location-shift alternative, it's a difference in means or medians as much as it is a median of pairwise differences.

See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88326/805) for a discussion of both the location-shift alternative and the more general alternative that the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney is sensitive to; there's some more discussion at the end of the post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67204/what-exactly-does-a-non-parametric-test-accomplish-what-do-you-do-with-the-res/67210#67210)

> Is it possible that A can be better than B and at the same time $E(X)<E(Y)$?

Certainly, if by 'better' you mean "has a high median pairwise difference".

Note that your density displays show a roughly similar asymmetric shape but quite different spread; that's one way (of a number of ways) you might see it. Different shapes but similar spread can also produce it. If there's *only* a shift in location, the difference in population means and population median-pairwise-difference will be the same - but even with a pure location-shift in the populations, the *samples* might show opposite shifts.

> Is the following methodology correct?

As expressed I don't understand it. For example, the comparison "if x==y" doesn't make sense - why would the samples be identical, and if they were, what would be the point in proceeding, since no test can find a difference?

> If I wish to test A against several algorithms B, C, ..., what could be the best approach to take?

What would be *best* depends on many things which I don't have the information to answer (if you want a nonparametric test I'd suggest considering permutation tests with good power against whatever alternative is of primary interest). The $k$-sample equivalent of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney would be the Kruskal-Wallis test, so if you're happy with the WMW, you might consider the KW.

Comment: Another way to view this test is that it assumes the two (continuous) distributions have identical shapes (after possibly undergoing a common monotonic transformation) but may have been location-shifted (post-transformation). Although this is a non-trivial distributional assumption it is still nonparametric. With it, one may indeed interpret the test as comparing medians. (The equal-shape assumption appears to be at least approximately true of the data shown in the question's graphic. A location shift in times could arise, say, by removing a $O(1)$ bottleneck in the algorithm.)

Comment: @whuber A 'same shape' assumption might be plausible, but the spreads don't seem to be: the leftmost lower peak and the rightmost higher peak are both from the same sample. That (and the related reversal in means vs median pairwise difference) suggests a straight location-shift may not be the case; it looks to me likely to be more complicated than a simple removal of an O(1) operation.

Comment: You're right: I simply misread the graph!  My eyes focused on common patterns and neglected the colors altogether.  Clearly the spreads differ.  What could rescue that analysis would be to identify a simple monotonic transformation after which there is a change of location.  For instance, replacement of a $O(2)$ algorithm by a $O(1)$ algorithm could result in an apparent location shift upon taking logarithms.  But, like you, I am not too optimistic about that (based on a more careful look at the graphics!).

Comment: @whuber My eyes did the same as yours the first few times I looked at it.